# Launching rmid problem on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, java

I have

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

installed.

When I type rmid in the command line, I get this error:

> ```
> Activation.main: warning: sun.rmi.activation.execPolicy system
> property unspecified and no ExecPermissions/ExecOptionPermissions
> granted; subsequent activation attempts may fail due to unsuccessful
> ExecPermission/ExecOptionPermission permission checks
>
> For documentation on how to configure rmid security, refer to:
>
> http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/docs/tooldocs/solaris/rmid.html
> http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/docs/tooldocs/win32/rmid.html
> ```

Naturally, neither link works.

I need rmid for a remote client/server project I'm working on. Any ideas to why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you need here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html